# jQuery menus with + and - for opening and closing submenus

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know any good jQuery menu which has + and - for opening and closing submenus.

I found in google only this:
http://berndmatzner.de/jquery/hoveraccordion/

but this does not have + and - for opening and closing menus and has only 1 submenu.

example

```
+ link
+ link 2
+ link 3
```

if i click on link2

```
+ link
- link 2
  + foo
  + foo2
+ link 3
```

Comment: + and - being what ? images ? and how should the submenus open ? click ? hover ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ιf you want to a more playful custom version, have a look at a prototype i made for a project..

http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/aJQNN/

---

**Update**

To bypass the click with the current code you need to add some code at the top of the `.click` handler.

So change

```
$('li').click(function() {
```

to

```
$('li').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName === 'A' &&
            e.target.href &&
            e.target.getAttribute('href') !== '#'){
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: @Gaby perfect solution. I like it too :)

Comment: But in demo i see you have problem with ΤΟΠΟΙ link which is in the same level as ΤΟΥΡΚΙΑ link but it is not shown on main... It is visible when you click on ΤΟΠΟΙ link which is not correct...

Comment: @senzacionale, it is not in the same level.. just the indenting is wrong in the source.. you can see a correctly indented version at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/aJQNN/8/

Comment: yes now i see. Thx for replay and thx for updated version. Is it possible not to hide other menus when click on +?. Now when i click on first + and then in second one third dissapear.

Comment: Yes it is http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/aJQNN/9/  Original concept was an attempt to make the menu look as breadcrumb .. .

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli. When i click on link it is not redirected to new page even if link is valid? Why?

Comment: @senzacionale updated answer with a workaround for the current code.. it might be better though to refactor the code and remove the click handler from the `li` and put it on the `+` element..

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI has the accordian menu :

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

You can change the open / close images using the 'icons' option

for example :

```
var icons = {
    header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
    headerSelected: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
};
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    icons: icons
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look [at](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/jquery_multi_level_css_menu_horizontal_blue/) and in the css instead of there arrow image give your + or - image.

Similar stuff [here](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/create-a-multilevel-dropdown-menu-with-css-and-improve-it-via-jquery) again change the image on hover.

hope this helps.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960741/vertical-navigation-that-shows-hidden-submenu-on-click-using-jquery)