# Adding animate to show/hide javascript function

Tags: javascript, animation, hide, show

This is the first javascript code I have written, and I am having some trouble. I am in the process of making a vertical menu that will show additional information for the link onclick, while also hiding the contents of any other link. I want to add the .animate 'slow' javascript to the function, but having some difficulty. This is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reveal(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display== 'block')
e.style.display= 'none';
   else
e.style.display= 'block';
e.style.opacity= '1';
    }
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function hide(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display== 'block')
e.style.display= 'none';
   else
e.style.display= 'none';
    }
 </script>
```

I have tried numerous ways to put the 'animate' tag in but can't seem to get it. Help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your HTML and if possible a jsFiddle showing the issue?

Comment: If you want to use animate, you need jQuery. There is no native JS called animate

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="reveal('foo');hide('too');">Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</a>
<div id="foo">This is foo</div>

<a href="#" onclick="reveal('too'); hide('foo');">Click here to toggle visibility of element #too</a>
<div id="too">This is too</div>

Comment: Oh, I had seen this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960741/vertical-navigation-that-shows-hidden-submenu-on-click-using-jquery and tried that and got that toggle animation to work. I just want to apply that same visual effect to what I made there

Comment: As mplungjan points out, animate (and hide) are jQuery functions. If you want to use them you'll need to include jQuery, otherwise you'll have to code the equivalent pure JavaScript functions yourself.

Comment: Okay, this is what I tried... still no effect though. I added `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>` before the script and then `        var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        $j(document).ready(function() {
        });` before the function. And `       $j(id).animate({height: 'toggle' ,opacity: 'toggle'}, "slow");` in the function, but still no effect

Comment: I tried setting up a jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/KMDjR/

Comment: are you sure js/jquery.js exists on your server? is there any errors on the console?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the fiddle, it seems very confusing. I came up with a cleaner set of codes you can use for now but you got a lot to learn. Fiddle added http://jsfiddle.net/KMDjR/7/ MAKE SURE you call jquery (in fiddle it is called on the left but in your page you need to call it yourself as my code below indicates)

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
#foo{
display: none;
}

#poo{
display: none;
}
</style>
<!-- calling jquery  -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.toggleFoo').live('click', function() {
        $('#foo').fadeIn(1000);
        $('#poo').fadeOut(1000);
    });

    $('.togglePoo').live('click', function() {
        $('#poo').fadeIn(1000);
        $('#foo').fadeOut(1000);
    });

});
</script>
</head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" class="toggleFoo">Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</a><br /><br />
        <div id="foo">This is foo</div>

        <a href="#" class="togglePoo">Click here to toggle visibility of element #poo</a><br /><br />
        <div id="poo">This is poo</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Huangism, I know I certainly have a long way to go with code (like I said, this is my first code I have ever written in javascript or jquery). Unfortunately, this did not work on my site. Perhaps there is a conflict http://hookahi.com/menu-test#

Comment: if you copy the core from the code I provided, it should do what you want but you should really start with basic javascript and work your way up. I also want that check mark!

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yeah I put the code in just as you have it, but I am not getting any response when I click the links. Did you look over the link I posted?

Comment: you mean the fiddle link? Ye i looked, it was a huge mess i will create a fiddle and attach it to my answer

Comment: I meant this one  hookahi.com/menu-test# it has the test page. I can't tell why it isn't working...

Comment: It was in the heading for the entire site, but I put in the page now to see

Comment: I think jquery is called in your site somewhere so you dont need to call again. whatever it is outputting the script lines, it added p tags which gives it a syntax error